# The right way to create custom dialog in Android

Tags: android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android

I want to build an custom `Dialog` for my app. I read about some different methods doing this, and I want to ask what is the different between them and what is more used and popular.

1. Extends `DialogFragment` and in `onCreateDialog` initialise it:

   ```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fmessage)
   //code
   //code


   return builder.create();
   ```
2. Extends `DialogFragment` and in `onCreateView` to inflate the layout:

   ```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.purchase_items, container, false);
   ```

   }
3. Dont use any extends simple define an instance type `Dialog` in Activity:

   ```
         Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CustomDialog.this);
           dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
           dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

           TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textDialog);
           //code
           //code
           //code

           dialog.show();
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Extends `DialogFragment` and in `onCreateDialog` initialise it:

If you want to use a simple dialog with two buttons, then you should follow this method by using `AlertDialog.Builder`. You can also set a custom layout by using `setView`. This will set a custom layout for the view **BETWEEN** the title and the buttons of this dialog.

2. Extends DialogFragment and in onCreateView to inflate the layout:

You should follow this method if you want to use a complete custom layout(title, icons, buttons etc.) for your dialog.

3. Dont use any extends simple define an instance type Dialog in Activity:

If you want to create a dialog in just one activity, then you should use this.

But, if you want to show the same dialog in various activities, then you should follow any of the previous two methods according to your requirements. Then you would be able to show the dialog from any of your activities and won't have to write the same code in every single activity.